# Strange behaviour with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have this code snippet that should `await` 5 promises, pause for 2 seconds and then continue to `await` another 5. However, the output shows that the two `Promise.all` are not awaited although when I tried to return a value in the promise it returns properly. Am I understanding the concept of `Promise.all` wrong or there is something missing in my code?

```js
(function () {
    let val = 0

    const promiseArr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        promiseArr[i] = new Promise((res) => {
            val += 500
            setTimeout((val2) => {
                console.log(val2)
                res()
            }, val, val)
        })
    }

    console.log();
    (async function() {
        await Promise.all(promiseArr.slice(0, 5))
        console.log('start await')
        await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 2000))
        console.log('done await')
        await Promise.all(promiseArr.slice(6, 10))
    })()
}) ()
```

Expected output:

```
500
...
2500
start await
done await
3000
...
5000
```

Actual output:

```
500
1000
1500
2000
2500
start await
3000
3500
4000
4500
done await
5000
```

**EDIT:**
Now I understand why it behaves like that. Looks like I misunderstood a fundamental concept with Promises. Thanks for you guys help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled on this misunderstanding myself too: when you define a Promise, it's function is executed in that moment. If I understand what you're trying to do, you need to define an array of functions, and call them as needed.

```
(function () {
    let val = 0

    const promiseArr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        promiseArr[i] = () => new Promise((res) => {
            val += 500
            setTimeout((val2) => {
                console.log(val2)
                res()
            }, val, val)
        })
    }

    console.log();
    (async function() {
        await Promise.all(promiseArr.slice(0, 5).map((fn) => fn()))
        console.log('start await')
        await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 2000))
        console.log('done await')
        await Promise.all(promiseArr.slice(6, 10).map((fn) => fn()))
    })()
}) ()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing this because the promises begin running as soon as they are created (or, well, as soon as the current synchronous block finishes anyway), not when they are `await`ed upon.

Instrumenting and reorganizing your code a little, to print timestamps for each event might illuminate things:

```
const t0 = +new Date();

const logWithTime = (message = "") =>
  console.log("" + Math.round(+new Date() - t0) + ": " + message);

(async function() {
  let val = 0;

  const resolver = res => {
    val += 500;
    const thisVal = val; // so we have a binding for the effective value
    logWithTime("Creating timeout for " + thisVal);
    setTimeout(
      arg => {
        logWithTime("Timeout for " + thisVal);
        res();
      },
      thisVal,
      thisVal,
    );
  };

  const promiseArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    promiseArr[i] = new Promise(resolver);
  }

  logWithTime("awaiting for first 5...");
  await Promise.all(promiseArr.slice(0, 5));
  logWithTime("waiting for 2 seconds...");
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 2000));
  logWithTime("waiting for the rest...");
  await Promise.all(promiseArr.slice(6, 10));
  logWithTime("all done");
})();
```

prints

```
0: Creating timeout for 500
10: Creating timeout for 1000
10: Creating timeout for 1500
10: Creating timeout for 2000
10: Creating timeout for 2500
10: Creating timeout for 3000
10: Creating timeout for 3500
10: Creating timeout for 4000
10: Creating timeout for 4500
10: Creating timeout for 5000
10: awaiting for first 5...
511: Timeout for 500
1011: Timeout for 1000
1515: Timeout for 1500
2013: Timeout for 2000
2510: Timeout for 2500
2511: waiting for 2 seconds...
3010: Timeout for 3000
3512: Timeout for 3500
4011: Timeout for 4000
4511: Timeout for 4500
4511: waiting for the rest...
5011: Timeout for 5000
5011: all done
```

(or thereabouts, depending on things).

You can see the order in which the timeouts get resolved there.

Answer (score 1):

Your timers start ticking when you call `setTimeout`, **not** when you `await` the promise that is resolved by them.

While `(res) => setTimeout(res, 2000)` runs, you have 4 prior `setTimeouts` which finish and call `console.log` before resolving.